# Databinding of Listview in custom contentview

Tags: xaml, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to create a contentview which has a listview xamarinforms.
I want to set a property of the contentview that is then used to bind the data to the listview.

Unfortunately I am not able to populate it. 
I broke down the example to get a poc. The desired result should be a contentpage with all the names.
Any helb appreciated. Thx in advance!

The example consists of:
**Contentpage:** 
  Adds the contentview. 
   It also has a bindingcontext to a viewmodel - CompanyVM.
  Sets Property PersonList of contentview to PersonVM.Personlist. (Unsure if correct)

**Contentview.XAML:**
  XAML of contentview
   Bindings for listview (unsure if correct)

**Contentview.cs**
  XAML code-behind
  Property Settings for contentview

**CompanyVM:**
  Viewmodel used

**Company & Person & Mockup**
  Simple  classed to work with

## Example

**ContentMainPage**

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:cv="clr-namespace:ContentViewExample.XAML"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:ContentViewExample.ViewModel"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ContentViewExample"
             x:Class="ContentViewExample.MainPage"
             x:Name="mainpage">

    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <vm:CompanyVM/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <StackLayout>
        <cv:personlistCV Company="{x:Reference mainpage }"/>
        <!--Is this correct?-->
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

```

**Contentview.XAML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="ContentViewExample.XAML.personlistCV"
             x:Name="cvPersons">
  <ContentView.Content>
      <StackLayout>
            <ListView x:Name="lstPerson"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Company.Persons}">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Label  Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>

        </StackLayout>
  </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

**Contentview.cs**

```
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace ContentViewExample.XAML
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class personlistCV : ContentView
    {
        public personlistCV ()
        {
            InitializeComponent ();
        }

        //CompanyProperty
        public static readonly BindableProperty CompanyProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create(
                "Company",
                typeof(CompanyVM),
                typeof(personlistCV),
                null);

        public personlistCV Company
        {
            set { SetValue(CompanyProperty, value); }
            get { return (personlistCV)GetValue(CompanyProperty); }
        }
    }
}
```

**CompanyVM**

```
namespace ContentViewExample.ViewModel
{
    public class CompanyVM: ViewModelBase
    {
        ObservableCollection<Person> persons;
        string companyname;

        public CompanyVM()
        {
            companyname = "Test Company";
            persons = new ObservableCollection<Person>();

            foreach (Person item in MockData.GetPeople())
                persons.Add(item);
        }

        public string Company
        {
            set { SetProperty(ref companyname, value); }
            get { return companyname; }
        }


        public ObservableCollection<Person> Persons
        {
            set { SetProperty(ref persons, value); }
            get { return persons; }
        }
    }
}
```

**Company & Person**

```
public class Company
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class Person
{
    public string Name{get;set;}
}

public static class MockData
{
    public static List<Person> GetPeople()
    {
        List<Person> tmp = new List<Person>
        {
            new Person
            {
                Name="Ted"
            },
            new Person
            {
                Name="Jennifer"
            },
            new Person
            {
                Name="Andy"
            },

            new Person
            {
                Name="Oscar"
            }
        };

        return tmp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to Make  `ItemsSource="{Binding Company.Persons}">` to  `ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}">` this in Contentview.XAML

Comment: hi @Arvindraja - Thank you for the hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have tried to bind `personlistCV.Company` the following way

```
<StackLayout>
    <cv:personlistCV Company="{x:Reference mainpage }"/>
    <!--Is this correct?-->
</StackLayout>
```

I see several issues here:

- Bindings are set with the XAML extension `Binding`
- The `Company` is set to the `mainpage`, which is of Type `MainPage`.

  - It should rather be set to `mainpage.BindingContext` (this is a `CompanyCV` object)

Furthermore the `personlistCV.Company` is of type `personlistCV`, which does not really make sense. The field should be of type `CompanyVM`, since we'd like to bind the viewmodel (and `personlistCV` does not even have a `Persons` (bindable) property).

Having said that, the following code should work:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:cv="clr-namespace:ContentViewExample.XAML"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:ContentViewExample.ViewModel"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ContentViewExample"
             x:Class="ContentViewExample.MainPage"
             x:Name="mainpage">

    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <vm:CompanyVM/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <StackLayout>
        <cv:personlistCV Company="{Binding Path=BindingContext, Source={x:Reference mainpage}}"/> <!-- Bind the element to `mainpage.BindingContext` --> 
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Maybe

```
<cv:personlistCV Company="{Binding .}"/>
```

could work, too, since `.` usually binds to the `BindingContext` of the view and the `BindingContext` of the page is passed down to the views (unless another `BindingContext` is set for the views explicitly).

And for the `companyCV`

```
public partial class personlistCV : ContentView
{
    public personlistCV ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
    }

    //CompanyProperty
    public static readonly BindableProperty CompanyProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(
            "Company",
            typeof(CompanyVM),
            typeof(personlistCV),
            null);

    public CompanyVM Company
    {
        set { SetValue(CompanyProperty, value); }
        get { return (personlistCV)GetValue(CompanyProperty); }
    }
}
```

Comment: @G.hakim While this is true, you should've commented and leave it to me to edit the answer. While changes that fix an answer or improve formatting are perfectly acceptable, I think that modifying the contents of an answer should be left to the original author of the answer.

Comment: As @G.hakim pointed out: there is a direct conversion from `List<>` to `ObservableCollection<>` so that foreach loop you have for filling mock data can be a one-liner something like this:

 `persons = new ObservableCollection<Person>(MockData.GetPeople());`

Comment: Hi @Paul-Kertscher thanks for the help.

-> Sorry if the example did not make much sense but your detailled answer helped me out because I am quite new to xaml.

1. Understanding that `x:References` actually references :) 
2. Using `Source` in binding to explicitly set the binding source.
3.  `{Binding .}` to use as short for Bindingreference of view.

Comment: @jan.michael Glad I could help :)